# How to replace text using perl/shell script?

Tags: replace, sed

I have one pattern

cat sample.text

```
\newline</Text>
```

I'm using the following command:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s|\newline</Text>|</Text>|g' sample.text
```

but following command is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\(<\/Text>\)/\1/;P;D' file
```

or

```
sed -r '$!N;s|\n(</Text>)|\1|;P;D' file
```

However if `\newline` is a literal:

```
sed 's/\\newline\(<\/Text>\)/\1/g' file
```

or

```
sed -r 's|\\newline(</Text>)|\1|g' file
```

Would work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to get rid of the newlines before `</Text>`? That's just a simple substitution:

```
gawk -vRS='\0' -vORS= '{gsub(/\n<\/Text>/,"</Text>")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution myself so thought to share with everyone.

```
 sed ':a; N; $!ba; s|\\newline<\/Text>|</Text>|g' sample.text
```